# workaround "This type of file can harm your computer" using robotframework

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

i have a test that uses chrome to download exe file using RBF and selenium and afterwards using RBF and winium i run the exe.

i am able to do it using python and selenium while modifying options for chrome 
[image]

but when using 'Create Webdriver' KW, my test is running too fast and my assertions for elements are failing one by one.

normally i used 'Open Browser' KW with timeout and implicit wait and speed which works like a charm 99% of the time.

is there a way to start webdriver without browsing protection using RBF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so after some research and several approaches I found a working solution to this problem.
the key is disabling safebrowsing using Webdriver ChromeOptions.
using pure python is pretty stright forward:

```
def customChromeOptions(self):
    self.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    self.chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    self.chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {'safebrowsing.enabled': 'false'})
    return self.chrome_options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=customChromeOptions().to_capabilities())
```

Implementing on robot framework was a bit more tricky (especially since trying to add custom robot library which is using SeleniumLibrary which did not go well) but eventually got it to work:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    Create Chrome Webdriver
    Go To    ${link to file download}

*** Keywords ***
Create Chrome Webdriver
    ${CHROME_OPTIONS}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${PREFS}    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${TEMP_DOWNLOADS_DIR}    safebrowsing.enabled=false
    Call Method    ${CHROME_OPTIONS}    add_argument    --start-maximized
    Call Method    ${CHROME_OPTIONS}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${PREFS}
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${CHROME_OPTIONS}
    Set Selenium Settings

Set Selenium Settings
    Set Selenium Speed    0.5
    Set Selenium Timeout    5
    Set Selenium Implicit Wait    30
```